# How to make a POST request for a blob in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ajax, post, http-post, blob

I have the following ajax code that makes a POST request for a blob to the server,and prints the returned data.

```
function upload(blob){

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', blob);

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://custom-url/record.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
    }
  });

}
```

How can I do the same thing in AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending the [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it is more efficient to send the [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) directly as the [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) has an extra 33% overhead.

```
var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } };

$http.post(url, blob, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;

    console.log("Success", status);
    return response; 
}).catch(function (errorResponse) {
    console.log("Error", errorResponse.status);
    throw errorResponse;
});
```

It as important to set the content type header to `undefined` so that the [XHR send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) can set the content type header. Otherwise the AngularJS framework will override with content type `application/json`.

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: How do we specify the file name in AngularJS? i.e. What's the equivalent of `'file'` in the line `formData.append('file', blob);`?